# AudioKit 5 -- how to normalize a file to target peak volume like AKAudioFile.normalize used to do

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Using AudioKit v5, I need to take an existing file and normalize the volume to a new max level.  Looking at older docs, it looks like the `AKAudioFile` type had a `normalized()` method that would do just that.  In AudioKit v5, the migration guide says `AKAudioFile` has been removed because `AVAudioFile` is good enough, but it looks like the `normalized()` function was lost with the change.

With AudioKit 5, what's the best way to approach normalize the file?  It looks like there's a `normalize` method on `AVAudioPCMBuffer` that scales the max amplitude to 1.  Is that the best approach, and then scale to the desired amplitude?